# cas.version=5.0.3.1 cas.apereo add authentification with FranceConnect openidConnect

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-config, cas, openid-connect

cas.version=5.0.3.1 cas.apereo add authentification with FranceConnect openidConnect

I configur FranceConnect protocol with openIDConnect with cas apereo version cas.version=5.0.3.1

```
I add in cas.properties

##
# CAS Authentication Attributes
#
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.uid=uid
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.displayName=displayName
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.cn=commonName
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.affiliation=groupMembership

cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.secret=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.discoveryUri=http://localhost:8082/cas/js/fc.json
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.useNonce=true
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.preferredJwsAlgorithm=HS256
cas.authn.pac4j.client.authn.typedidused=true
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.maxClockSkew=30

In my configuration cas i have tow connexion , i add thirth connexion with openid

@Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    private ClientAuthenticationHandler clientAuthenticationHandler;

 final Map<AuthenticationHandler, PrincipalResolver> handlerResolverMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        handlerResolverMap.put(clientAuthenticationHandler, new PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver());

@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfig  {

    @Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    private ClientAuthenticationHandler clientAuthenticationHandler;

    /**
     * Initialisation du manager d'authentification
     *
     * @return Objet AuthenticationManager
     */

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpClient simpleHttpClient) {
        // Initialisation du CAS manager
        final PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager policyBasedAuthenticationManager = new PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager();



        // Handler et Resolver correspondants
        final Map<AuthenticationHandler, PrincipalResolver> handlerResolverMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        handlerResolverMap.put(clientAuthenticationHandler, new PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver());
        handlerResolverMap.put(authenticationHandlerImpl(), principalResolver());
        handlerResolverMap.put(serviceTicketAuthenticationHandler(), serviceTicketCredentialsToPrincipalResolver());
        policyBasedAuthenticationManager.setHandlerResolverMap(handlerResolverMap);

        // Populators
        final List<AuthenticationMetaDataPopulator> populators = new ArrayList<>();
        populators.add(authenticationMetaDataPopulator());
        policyBasedAuthenticationManager.setAuthenticationMetaDataPopulators(populators);

        return policyBasedAuthenticationManager;
    }
}
```

The problem: clientAuthenticationHandler is always null

Do you have a solution for implimenation please?
I already have two connection mode configured
Thank you for your help

Regard,
Kamel